# Unable to hide bounding boxes and labels in YOLOv8

Tags: yolov8

I'm trying to hide the bounding boxes and the labels after a prediction in YOLOv8. I've set the necessary attributes but I still see the bounding boxes and labels in the final `render.show()`. What am I doing wrong?

```
# load model
model = YOLO('ultralyticsplus/yolov8m')

# set model parameters
conf = 0.2
iou = 0.5
ag_nms = False

# try to turn off bounding boxes and labels
model.overrides['hide_labels'] = True
model.overrides['hide_conf'] = True
model.overrides['show'] = False

# set image
image = 'pic.jpg'

# perform inference
results = model.predict(
    image,
    show=False,
    hide_labels=True,
    hide_conf=True,
    conf=conf,
    iou=iou,
)

# observe results
render = render_result(model=model, image=image, result=results[0])
render.show() # still sees the bounding boxes here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters `hide_labels`, `hide_conf` seems to be deprecated and will be removed in 'ultralytics 8.2'. Try to use the actual parameters instead:

```
show_labels=False
show_conf=False
```

I don't know what is 'render' in your script, but I suppose you don't need to directly override the model using `model.overrides()` to hide boxes, just use the suitable parameter for `model.predict()`:

```
boxes=False
```

The actual Yolov8 parameters are here: https://docs.ultralytics.com/usage/cfg/#predict

Comment: Thanks! You made me realized that I'm using the huggingface version of YOLOv8 which is different. Once I switched it back to the base version it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do anything inside the code, you just need to type show_boxes=False while running the code and it will remove all the boxes and confidence scores

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).